# Did Joseph II introduce the presumption of innocence in his legal code?

Tags: europe, law

The Holy Roman Emperor Joseph II has pushed through some important reforms. E.g. strongly reducing death penalty or abolishing serfdom. His legal code ([Josephina](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephinisches_Strafgesetz)) was in many ways revolutionary, one of which should be the presumption of innocence.

I am writing this question because I need some source to backup this information.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might give more background. Who is Joseph II? Presumably a king, what time, what country? If your Joseph II is the one I think it is, he was an unusually kind, "enlightened" ruler. This "color" would support a theory about why he "introduced presumption of innocence in his legal code," at a time when this would have been unusual. This has the makings of a good question, but needs to be fleshed out with more details.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the answer while extending my question. I had to search in through some Czech theses.

Comment: You are perhaps refering to the *[Josephina](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephinisches_Strafgesetz)*, not the *[Ferdinandae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_II,_Holy_Roman_Emperor)*.

Comment: I am indeed, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presumption of innocence was introduced by the law code from 1804. This law code was based on Joseph II's (Holy Roman Emperor) work.

Source: a book called "Birth modern Criminal Law on Territory Habsburg Monarchy and Criminal Law from of the year 1803", mentioned in this thesis (Czech): "Důležitou změnou oproti praxi minulých dob byla
presumpce neviny, oproti presumpci viny.[119]" - http://is.muni.cz/th/215281/ff_m/diplomova_prace.txt

Comment: This was Joseph II, the son of Maria Theresa, an advocate of "enlightened despotism," right? That's what I needed to know to answer your question. But it seems that you've found the answer. +1.